# What is the correct way to use StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(pth) in Windows 8

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-8, windows-runtime, storagefile

I have a method that returns the correct path to a file

```
    StorageFile newFile = null;
        try
        {
            string pth = Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, dbPath);
            newFile = StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(pth).GetResults(); ;
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException) { newFile = null; }
        if (newFile == null)
        {
            string pth = Package.Current.InstalledLocation.Path + @"\Scriptures\" + dbPath;
            StorageFile oldFile = StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(pth).GetResults();
            newFile = oldFile.CopyAsync(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder, dbPath, NameCollisionOption.FailIfExists).GetResults();
        }
        if (newFile == null) { throw new FileNotFoundException("Database File not Found"); }
        return newFile.Path;
```

However I sometimes get an error when it gets to

```
    StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(pth).GetResults()
```

The error that is thrown is:

```
   StorageFile newFile = null;
        try
        {
            string pth = Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, dbPath);
            newFile = StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(pth).GetResults(); ;
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException) { newFile = null; }
        if (newFile == null)
        {
            string pth = Package.Current.InstalledLocation.Path + @"\Scriptures\" + dbPath;
            StorageFile oldFile = StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(pth).GetResults();
            newFile = oldFile.CopyAsync(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder, dbPath, NameCollisionOption.FailIfExists).GetResults();
        }
        if (newFile == null) { throw new FileNotFoundException("Database File not Found"); }
        return newFile.Path;
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm new to c# and threading and this error is killing me because sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't.
Please help!

Comment: try newFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(pth);

Answer (score -2):

No permissions in runtime app！You cant access file with this method.
Check this [page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh967755.aspx)

Comment: While this may answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include more of the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Also, saying "this API doesn't work at all in the only environment in which it is provided" is a rather peculiar assertion.